# Evaluation Control for interpolating functions

Tags: evaluation, warning-messages, hold, attributes

I would like to find the root of the third component of an interpolating function, here e.g. a BezierFunction p:

```
tab = Table[{Tan[u], Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0., 2. Pi}]
p = BezierFunction[tab]
Plot[p[x][[3]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Now I would like to extract the root of the third component of the function like so:

```
FindRoot[p[u][[3]], {u, .2}]
```

However, differently to the Plot function before, this does not work:

> Part::partw: Part 3 of BezierFunction[{{0.,1.}},<>][u] does not exist.

- Why is Mathematica treating `Plot` and `FindRoot` in this regard differently? Both have the Attribute `HoldAll`.
- How do i modify the line `FindRoot[p[u][[3]], {u, .2}]`, so I am getting the right result for `u`?

Comment: Have you seen [`Indexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html)?  The attribute `HoldAll` means that evaluation is held until it gets inside the function. After that, it's up to the function when the expression gets evaluated.   Many functions in Mathematica evaluate the expression symbolically for various reasons (to find out if the derivatve/Jacobian can be computed, for instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1.* The attribute `HoldAll` means that evaluation is held until the arguments get inside the function. After that, it's up to the function when the expressions are evaluated. Many functions in *Mathematica* evaluate the expression symbolically for various reasons (to find out if the derivative/Jacobian can be computed, for instance, which `FindRoot` might do). `Plot` also turns off a lot of messages, so the `Part::partw` error might be happening inside `Plot` without your knowing it.  For `Plot`, a function not evaluating to a real number is not considered a serious problem.  It usually just creates a gap in the graph that is drawn.

*2.* I get three messages, the second and third ones being the telling ones, not the first message that was quoted in the OP:

```
FindRoot[p[u][[3]], {u, .2}]
```

> Part::partw: Part 3 of BezierFunction[{{0.,1.}},<>][u] does not exist.
>
> Part::partw: Part 3 of BezierFunction[{{0.,1.}},<>][-0.729293] does not exist.
>
> FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {BezierFunction[{{0.,1.}},<>][-0.729293][[3]]} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {u} = {-0.729293}.
>
> ```
> {u -> 0.2}
> ```

The input `-0.729293` lies outside the domain and the Bezier function does not extrapolate.  This is an error that `FindRoot` does not recover from.  The first message is only a warning.

To get a solution, add the domain as search boundaries:

```
FindRoot[p[u][[3]], {u, .2, 0, 1}]
```

> Part::partw: Part 3 of BezierFunction[{{0.,1.}},<>][u] does not exist.
>
> ```
> {u -> 0.}
> ```

Another root:

```
FindRoot[p[u][[3]], {u, .5, 0, 1}]
```

> Part::partw: Part 3 of BezierFunction[{{0.,1.}},<>][u] does not exist.
>
> ```
> {u -> 0.521603}
> ```

If you want to get rid of the warning, an alternative to defining a `NumericQ`-protected objective function is to use `Indexed`:

```
FindRoot[Indexed[p[u], 3], {u, .5, 0, 1}]
```

> ```
> {u -> 0.521603}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here my workaround for your second question:

```
eq[u_?NumericQ] := p[u][[3]]
opt=NMinimize[{1, 0 == eq[u], 0 < u < 1} , u]
(* {1., {u -> 0.521603}} *)
```

Comment: With more appropriate initial guess `FindRoot` can also be used: `FindRoot[eq[u]==0,{u,0.5}]`.

Comment: Yes but you have to know the right starting value! For example `FindRoot[eq[u] == 0, {u, .85 }]`fails!

Comment: Of course, using `FindRoot` obviously means one knows good starting values, without that `FindRoot` is useless. I only wrote that comment to show that OP can make use `FindRoot` as he wants/needs.